# Make jQuery remove animation in else statement

Tags: jquery, animation, resize

I am trying to stop a .slideUp animation that is called below 768px. The desired result is working until I resize back above 768px which then causes my desktop styled menu to slide up out of view.

The reason behind this is because I'm using angular to change page content and want the mobile experience to close the menu after a link has been clicked.

Is there a way to tell my else statement to remove the .slideUp animation altogether?

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on("load resize", function () { 
    if ($(this).width() < 768) {
        $('.lnk').on('click', function () { 
            $('#navigation').slideUp(500);
        });
    }else{
        // Things I've tried:

        // $('.lnk').on('click', function () { 
        // return false
        // });

        // $('.lnk').on('click', function () { 
        // $('#navigation').stop();
        // });

        // $('.lnk').on('click', function () { 
        // $('#navigation').slideDown();
        // });

        // $('.lnk').on('click', function () { 
        // $('#navigation').show();
        // });
    }
});
```

In theory, I could probably get away with leaving it as I have it because there wont be too many people actually resizing their browser when they visit, but I'm pedantic.

Comment: Does $('#navigation').hide() work?

Comment: I haven't tried that but I suspect it would remove the menu entirely for users on devices above 768px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an answer and had to re-write my code to get a working result.

I'm not going to accept this an answer as it does not address my question, I just wanted to follow up with the solution I went with.

So instead of having a way to just remove the slideToggle option, I changed my function to add, remove or toggle classes, depending on the windows size on load and resize.

This solution also removes the smooth animation due to the `height:auto` property. A smooth transition can be achieved if you set the height to a static value, ie. `height:300px`

**CSS**

```
#navigation {
    height:0;
}
.responsive_nav_open {
    height:auto
}
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    (function ($) { 
        $('.responsive_nav').on('click', function () {
            $('#navigation').toggleClass('responsive_nav_open');
        });
        $('.lnk').on('click', function () { 
            $('#navigation').toggleClass('responsive_nav_open');
        });
        $(window).on('load resize', function () { 
        if ($(this).width() <= 768) {
            $('#navigation').removeClass('responsive_nav_open');
        } else {
            $('#navigation').addClass('responsive_nav_open');
        }
    } );

    } )(jQuery);
    </script>
```

If someone could address the original question, just to clarify if it's actually possible or not, I'd still be interested to know.